# How can I get the database of an app that only has a search field

Tags: python, database, mobile, web-crawler, extract

Here in Brazil, the government made an app that you can type in the name of the item, for example *"Refined Sugar 2kg"* and the app return to you the location of the nearest market that has the cheapest item.
It extends to all sort of products, and I'm thinking about creating an app using that database. It is public, so it's not a crime, but they do not list all the products on the screen right away with categories and etc. The app only have a search bar, and that's it.
How can I get that database? I thought of an crawler (probably python), but all the crawlers that i see has an webpage as a 'target'. I never programmed mobile, so I don't know if a crawler can do that job.
**So, what should I study in order to make an tool to extract that information?**

Comment: Email them and ask them if you can have the data. If you can't, you're likely competition. Presumably they would monetise it through ads or something (I'm not sure why a government would build such a thing but I can definitely be wrong without knowing enough about the location).

Comment: Is there a public API to use?

Comment: It's not competition, because they don't profit from it. It's a government app. It's just a tool that they made available. No, I don't think that is.

Comment: I'm really curious about why the government would build such a thing? For sure I could be well of the mark; why invest national finance in such a project?

Comment: "It is public, so it's not a crime"  Just because someone made a public frontend does not mean it will be legal to hack your way to the DB in the backend.

Comment: Probably so that the costumers could buy the cheapest products.

Comment: @DeepSpace Ok, so... THAT I can't confirm. I'm just thinking that if they made it possible to search for all the products that you want, it wouldn't be a problem to me (or anyone) to get that databse of prices and use.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous I just want to know the way. I don't even know how to start to building such an app to sweep through the database.

Comment: Is this a publicly available web app? If so you can open up the devtools in your web browser and view the network traffic. You can inspect the actual urls that the app is getting its data from. If you are lucky this is an api that provides some way to fetch the data you want.

Answer (score 2):

**"How can I get that database? "**  The legal way would be to just *ask them* for it. Their database likely has passwords/etc which means it is not meant for public use outside of the functionality that the application you mentioned provides. **Are there ways to access this data without asking the owner of the information?** Possibly. But to *attain* the data in any other way then asking for it and receiving it, then my friend you are entering a grey area. A crawler won't be much help for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok, so... That database is not actually restricted. Here in Brasil we have something that I can't really translate, that is "nota fiscal". It's like a receipt that every store has to give to the costumer. It has all the taxes information and etc. So, everytime you buy something you get that receipt. Recently, the government adopted an "Online receipt" So, you still receive that piece of paper, but at the same time, it goes to the government database. They just made an app so you can search the cheapest product of the stores t hat uses that "Online receipt".

Comment: Link, please! This sounds interesting.